# Filter array that contains optional - SearchBar

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

just a bit of hindsight for you to understand my problem. I am currently coding an iOS app for events where I have a GuestList CoreData saved on device.

On viewDidLoad, it will fetch the coredata object and place it into an array of [GuestDetails]

Now the Guestdetail object struct is as follows:

```
private(set) public var guestFirstName: String
private(set) public var guestLastName: String?
private(set) public var guestEmail: String?
private(set) public var guestPhone: String?
private(set) public var guestUUID: UUID
private(set) public var guestBarcode: String?
private(set) public var guestCheckedIn: Bool
```

Such that only first name, UUID and checkinStatus are compulsory. I have already set up adding by JSON but now my issue is on my GuestListViewController, I have a searchbar

[image: Guest List Page]

I am using the following code and array to make sure I can filter.
I have another array that is called

```
searchResultArray = [GuestDetails]()
```

So essentially I would copy all my guest details to searchResultArray and that is the one that the tableView is getting its sources from.

Now as part of the search, I used this code which I found on appcoda

```
searchResultArray = guestData.filter({guestData -> Bool in
   (guestData.guestFirstName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) || 
   (guestData.guestLastName?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))! ||
   (guestData.guestBarcode?.contains(searchText))!
})
```

The issue is that my app is crashing, if I only search by first name it will not crash since those are force unwrapped nicely, but if I add the code to search lastName or Barcode, it will crash. I understand that it is probably because of explicitly unwrapped but xcode would not let me NOT unwrap it.

- I have tried using map (which does not help, unless i am not familiar enough with it),
- I have tried .compact (but I could not get it to work as i am not sure how it can access the inside of an GuestDetail object to remove nils)
- The issue is the array of [GuestDetails] itself will not contain null some details inside a GuestDetails object might, hence causing it to crash.

My question is, how do I get it to search by firstname(already possible), lastname and barcode?

Thanks and I hope the question was elaborate enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using forced unwrapping like so:

```
searchResultArray = guestData.filter({guestData -> Bool in
    let searchLowercased = searchText.lowercased()
    if guestData.guestFirstName.lowercased().contains(searchLowercased) {
        return true
    }

    if let guestLastName = guestData.guestLastName, guestLastName.lowercased().contains(searchLowercased) {
        return true
    }

    if let guestBarcode = guestData.guestBarcode, guestBarcode.lowercased().contains(searchLowercased) {
        return true
    }

    return false
})
```

Answering your question from comments: You don't have to use `?` operator on optionals because we use Optional Binding `if let` syntax. So for example:

`if let guestLastName = guestData.guestLastName` if `guestData.guestLastName` is `nil` than we will just jump out of this `if statement`. then you see `,` in the `if statement`, we will go pass this comma only if `guestData.guestLastName` is not `nil`, that is why we can use the `guestLastName` variable that is unwrapped `String` and is no longer optional `String?`, we than proceed to check if search term matches the `guestLastName` and `return true`.

Please read: [if let , if var, guard let,guard var and defer statements in swift](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/if-let-if-var-guard-let-and-defer-statements-in-swift-4f87fe857eb6)

It would be even better if you happen to add another property to your Data and avoid doing all this `if else` you can do something like:

```
searchResultArray = guestData.filter({guestData -> Bool in
    let searchLowercased = searchText.lowercased()
    let matches:[String?] = [guestData.guestFirstName, guestData.guestLastName, guestData.guestBarcode]
    let nonNilElements = matches.compactMap { $0 }

    for element in nonNilElements {
        if element.lowercased().contains(searchLowercased) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
})
```

Comment: is that a comma after 
let guestLastname = guestData.guestLastName ? cause xcode would not let me do that

Comment: oh it does. what is this kind of syntax called? sorry i'm quite new

Comment: it works! and it compiles and searches nicely! could you explain to me what is this syntax called? where you add a comma after? so I can research on that and learn

Comment: @KelvinChong condition list. See http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_conditional_binding

Comment: @KelvinChong and get @matt's  `iOS 11 Programming Fundamentals with Swift` book  and you will ace Swift and iOS development , highly recommended!

Comment: @matt for the second example what would work nicer than the `for` iteration and comparing each element to the search term...

Comment: I think it’s very nice! You could map instead of looping, but your way is more efficient because you return early if there is a match.

Comment: @matt ok great, thanx!

Comment: @Ladislav For some improvements, use `??` and `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`. See my "answer". (It's not meant to compete with your answer, but I can't post code without answering.)

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting little problem, so let's generalize it. Here's our test data, comparable to your array of GuestDetails:

```
struct S {
    var s1 : String
    var s2 : String?
    var s3 : String?
}

var array = [S]()
array.append(S(s1: "test", s2: "yo", s3: "ha"))
array.append(S(s1: "test", s2: nil, s3: nil))
array.append(S(s1: "Howdy", s2: "Bonjour", s3: "Hello"))

let target = "hello"
```

Some S properties are Optional, others are not.

So the problem is: Filter `array` down to only those elements where *any* S property contains our `target` string, using case insensitive comparison.

We can do that in one statement:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter {
    [$0.s1,$0.s2,$0.s3].compactMap {$0}
        .map {$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(target)}
        .contains(true)
}
```

It's not quite as efficient as what @Ladislav wrote, because we keep looping inside `map` even after we've found our string. But the inefficiency is probably not significant.